# Swift Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xe7ffdefe)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crash, audiokit

I am playing a 2500 Hz sound on iPhone 4s iOS(9.3.5) and by debugging i get this error.

```
override func viewDidLoad()
     {    
     AKSettings.defaultToSpeaker = true
                    do{
                        try AKSettings.setSession(category: AKSettings.SessionCategory.playback, with: .defaultToSpeaker)
                    }catch{
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                    
                    let file_input = try? AKAudioFile(readFileName: "2.5kz_sound.wav")
                    player = AKPlayer(audioFile: file_input!)
                    if !AudioKit.engine.isRunning {
                        try? AudioKit.start()
                    }
                    
                    player.play()
    }
```

I get this error on **AKsettings.setsession** line
and sometimes audio is not playing on iOS 13.5

Comment: "sometimes audio is not playing on iOS 13.5"  That's probably because you don't set an audio file to a variable, which should be loaded when you launch the app.

Comment: Try setting up your AKSettings when the user did appear.

Comment: tried but nothing worked.and what about the crash issue ? why it occurs

Comment: Ask you question at their GitHub.  I misunderstood that AKSettings is part of AVFoundation.